# Changes made to html pages does not reflect in android application

Tags: php, android, html, apache2

i am using apache2 as app server and am using php and html pages to do database operations in localhost, everything was working fine then suddenly,

if i do alterations to my html pages, it is not reflecting in the same page which is loading in android application without my alterations why is this ?

Then i opened firefox and loaded the samepage, in firefox the updated page is loading correctly!!

All i did today was that i changed wifi networks, then my ip changed, i changed it in android code, then i switched back to old, first used wifi network, corresponding changes were made in android codes also

After this the webpage loading via webview is not altering

first code

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>mukund</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>rahul</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

added

```
<tr>
<td>robin</td>
</tr>
```

after rahul

Comment: Provide us the code where you made alterations

Comment: go to `AppSettings` --> click `clear Data` and `clear cache` and then try.

Comment: dat worked, now do i have to do dis all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Rename the page, load it on the app, if you get a 404 error, go back and rename it to original name!

Make sure to restart app each time.

Comment: here is wat i did, i copied the code made a new file, deleted the old file and loaded it again, now the altered page loaded correctly in new name when i clicked in it, then i created another file in which only 'mukund' is given as code, and saved it in the name of deletd file and loaded it via app! surprisingly the page i deleted loaded again! i mean dere were no codes to load that, even then it loaded the deleted page just because name was same

Comment: When you delete the old page, restart app then load and check for 404 error. 
Comment if you get 404